# Vector Cross product in C

Tags: c, vector, cross-product

I am trying to write a code to solve the cross product of two 3D vectors. I need to be able to input the X,Y,Z values of the vector and then have it output the cross product of the two vectors. When I run the program it returns a value of zero. Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int a,b,c;
   int x,y,z;
   int A[3],B[3];
   int sum = 0;
   int i;

  void vector_product(int A[i], int B[i])
 {
  sum += ((b*z)-(c*y))+((a*z)-(c*x))+((a*y)-(b*x));
 }

int main(void)
{

  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",&A[i]);
 }
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&B[i]);
  }

    int A[3] = {a, b, c};
    int B[3] = {x, y, z};
    vector_product(A,B);
    printf("%d\n",sum);

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What happens *directly after* you read the input? Perhaps you should find some good beginners book and read about *scope* and variable shadowing.

Comment: Yes, what that programmer dude said.  Looks like you need to study up on some of the basics of C.  Your scoping is definitely a problem, as is some of your syntax.  (hint: `int A[3] = {a, b, c};` does not do what you think it does; scope is only one part of the problem with that line of code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to make `a`, `b`, and `c` refer to `A[0]`, `A[1]`, and `A[2]`, but that is not what happens.

The lines

```
int A[3] = {a, b, c};
int B[3] = {x, y, z};
```

shadow the global variables `A` and `B`, and initialize those two vectors with `{0,0,0}` (because a,b,c,x,y, or z are never set). Then in your `vector_product` function, you use `a`,`b`,`c`, etc. and don't use the two arrays you passed in. I'd recommend doing what Some Programmer Dude said and finding/re-reading a book on C, particularly the section on arrays.